# Store List of data in Redis and query based on filter applied on Redis Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have List of the object which I want to store in Redis.
After the store, I want to retrieve based on the filter applied to it.
Now I want to retrieve students who belong to a particular course and admission date in a range and
id should be in range. How can we achieve this requirement using java code?

```
Class student
{
   private int id;
   private int course_id;
   private date addmisson_date;
   private string name;

}
```

List which need to store.